# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 515738]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

First I wanted to say that this is my first time trying this. Secondly, I'm not sure I'm placing this question at the right forum. If not, please excuse me.

I'm trying to use Naive Bayes on my data. Click [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jiashenliu/515k-hotel-reviews-data-in-europe) to download the dataset.

This is my code till now:

```
data = pd.read_json('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews.json')
data.head()

#stopword are not usefull (a, and, the)
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, lowercase=True, strip_accents='ascii', stop_words=stopset)

y = data['Reviewer_Score']
X = scipy.sparse.hstack([vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Negative_Review']),
                        vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Positive_Review'])]
                       )

#515738 observations and 106514 unique words
print (y.shape)
print (X.shape)

#split the data - 0.2 means 20% of the data. 123 means use same dataset with every test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=123)

#train naive bayes classifier
clf = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/traintestfile.py in 
     33 #train naive bayes classifier
     34 clf = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
---> 35 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     36 
     37 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    618 
    619         labelbin = LabelBinarizer()
--> 620         Y = labelbin.fit_transform(y)
    621         self.classes_ = labelbin.classes_
    622         if Y.shape[1] == 1:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    458             Shape will be [n_samples, 1] for binary problems.
    459         """
--> 460         return self.fit(y).transform(y)
    461 
    462     def transform(self, y):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in fit(self, y)
    435 
    436         self.sparse_input_ = sp.issparse(y)
--> 437         self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
    438         return self
    439 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in unique_labels(*ys)
     95     _unique_labels = _FN_UNIQUE_LABELS.get(label_type, None)
     96     if not _unique_labels:
---> 97         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
     98 
     99     ys_labels = set(chain.from_iterable(_unique_labels(y) for y in ys))

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 7.5,  9.2,  9.2, ...,  5.8, 10. ,  9.6]),)
```

Could please somebody help me out? I'm stuck. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what and can't seem to find anything on the Internet to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only vectorize one column at a time, and seems like you have a typo at `vectorizer.fit_transform(['Negative_Review', 'Positive_Review'])` where the dataframe is not used.

Below should work, where the vectorizer is done on the 2 columns separately and then concatenated:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import scipy

data = pd.read_csv('Hotel_Reviews.csv.zip')
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, lowercase=True, strip_accents='ascii', stop_words=stopset)

y = data["Reviewer_Score"]
x = scipy.sparse.hstack([vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Negative_Review']),
                        vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Positive_Review'])]
                       )

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=123)
```

Comment: But I got another error now. See my original question!

Comment: hey. I solved the original question. if you have a new error, please post a new question. this is not a discussion forum or troubleshooting for scikit-learn

Comment: Oh , it said edit your original question if '...'.But oke, I will ask a new question. Thank you!

Comment: I took a look. your y variable is continuous. you are trying to do a classification.